# HttpPost in windows 8 Store XAML/C#

Tags: c#, android, windows, windows-8

I developed an app for android who sends a request to a sever, my code in Android is the following:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.something.com");
List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login-form-type", "pwd"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

I have tried some examples but it seems that a standard C# code even in visual Studio 2012 doesn't work as usual in a Windows Store App Can anyone help me to understand how this code would work in a Windows 8 Store App.

I really apreciate your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are [resources for Android --> Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945421.aspx), including an [API mapping index](http://apimappingsite.cloudapp.net/library?source=Android#Android-Android).  Here's the [article on how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945420.aspx).

In addition, there's a program called [Generation App](http://aka.ms/Jen30TLWin8) that helps you build your first app following a guided learning path.  It also gives you free access to tech support and free design consultations (Microsoft employees aren't eligible; I would have loved a free design consult on my apps!), and there are occasionally giveaways for submitting apps.